# I cannot print PDF documents that contains graphics on Brother All in one

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf

I installed drivers (through `Driver Install Tool`) from [Brother's webpage](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=pl&lang=pl&prod=dcp1510e_eu&os=128&flang=English) for my all in one (DCP-1510e) device.

Scanning works perfectly. I am also able to print test-page and print the document that I created in simple text editor.

However, I am unable to print PDF document. According to pop-ups document should be printed, but it is not the case. In 'Printers' there's no error message visible.

I removed printer from 'Printers' and added it again, but it doesn't help.
I've also tried to print the document to cups-pdf printer first and then print it on Brother printer, but it also doesn't help.

---

Is there any possibility to "debug" what is the source of my issue? Is it possible that this is caused by lack of permissions by current user or some missing packages?